# Is there any way to convert a superclass pointer to subclass pointer by subclass name in c++ string?

Tags: c++, c++11

Recently, I'm working on something like reflection in c++ using by my plugin system. Right now, I wonder if I can convert a super-class pointer into sub-class pointer given the string name of sub-class:

```cpp
class SuperClass
{
public:
  SuperClass(const string &name):class_name(name){}
  // a convert function like
  // return value should variant like SubClassA * or SubClassB *
  // SubClassA * ConvertByName();

private:
  string class_name;
};

class SubClassA: public SuperClass
{
public:
  SubClassA():SuperClass("SubClassA")
};

class SubClassB: public SuperClass
{
public:
  SubClassB():SuperClass("SubClassB")
}
```

when using:

```cpp
// some place create instance
SuperClass *one = new SubClassA；
SuperClass *two = new SubClassB;


// other place using
auto a = one->ConvertByName();  // a is of type SubClassA
auto b = two->ConvertByName();  // b is of type SubClassB
```

Can it be realized? Or is there any better way in c++?

**[Update 1]**

There my be some other sub-classes, such as, SubClassC, SubClassD, ...
So basically, we don't know what and how many sub-classes are derived from this SuperClass. What we know about sub-class is only its class name in string format.

**[Update 2]**

My motivation

I need this for plugin system. I want to create a plugin anytime, but don't want hack into my plugin core system codes. That is plugin codes are isolated from projects. A plugin system will never know what and how many plugins are added into system until runtime

Comment: Type must be determined at compile-time, and I assume the strings are only known at runtime, so it's not possible in general. What do you need this kind of reflection for?

Comment: Frustrating! Recently, I have done is creating a sub-class instance and assigning it  as pointer to super-class pointer variable, in a plugin system. Now, I need to recovery this pointers into specific sub-class type at runtime.

Comment: *"recovery this pointers into specific sub-class type at runtime"* And what do you need this for? This exact thing is impossible, but if we understand your goal, we might be able to suggest a workaround.

Comment: This is not the right approach in a language like c++. Better to explain what you want to achieve and people can tell you how to do it instead of asking for what you think you need.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I have updated my question. I need this for plugin system. I want to create a plugin anytime, but don't want hack into my former codes too much. That is plugin codes are isolated from projects. A plugin system will never know what and how many plugins are added into system until runtime.

Comment: @Mr.Frog: don't comment your question, but please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64290602/edit) it to provide motivation

Comment: Ok, but what stops you from only dealing with pointers to the base class?

Comment: This is not how object orientation works at all. Writhe this on the blackboard 100 times: "Everything I need to do with a subclass, I shall only do by calling a virtual function defined in the base class".

Comment: So from: `What we know about sub-class is only its class name in string format.` Do you just want the string name? Do you want `typeid(*b).name()`?

Answer (score 1):

If your classes all have some `virtual` thing, consider using `dynamic_cast`

See [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) for details, and read a good [C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html).

Read also the documentation of your C++ compiler (e.g. [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org))

> Right now, I wonder if I can convert a super-class pointer into sub-class pointer given the string name of sub-class

### This is not possible without specific coding and programming conventions

(since the class names do not exist at runtime). Look inside [Qt](https://qt.io/) or [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) as an example.

A possible approach could be to write your C++ code generator to help you (so *generate* parts of your C++ code - probably some header file containing your `class` declarations-, like Qt does with its [moc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/why-moc.html), and configure your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool, e.g. your `Makefile`). Look perhaps inside [ANTLR](https://antlr.org/), [SWIG](https://swig.org/), [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp), etc...

A more ambitious approach, if you use GCC, would be to write your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html). Consider also extending [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/). This is worthwhile only for *large* existing code bases.

> A plugin system will never know what and how many plugins are added into system until runtime

It seems that you are designing some plugin machinery. Take inspiration from [Qt plugins](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/plugins-howto.html) or [FLTK plugins](https://www.fltk.org/doc-1.4/classFl__Plugin__Manager.html). If on Linux, see [manydl.c](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/manydl.c) and consider generating some of the C++ code of your plugins (see e.g. this [draft report](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf), and the [CHARIOT](http://chariotproject.eu/) and [DECODER](https://www.decoder-project.eu/) European projects).

BTW, do you want to unload plugins (on Linux, call [dlclose(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlclose.3.html); read also then the [C++ dlopen minihowto](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/C++-dlopen/))? Do you have a multi-threaded application? If you do, you'll better have some locking (e.g. `std::mutex`) to avoid parallel plugin loading.

You could also consider generating at runtime some glue code: e.g. using [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) or [asmjit](https://github.com/asmjit/asmjit), or simply generating some temporary C++ code (e.g. on Linux in `/tmp/generated.cc` that you would compile - maybe with [popen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) - using `g++ -Wall -O -fPIC /tmp/generated.cc -o /tmp/generated-plugin.so`) and later [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) that `/tmp/generated-plugin.so`. Read Drepper's paper [*how to write shared libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) (for Linux).

Comment: Thanks Basile. I will read details of the QT or RefPerSys as examples and will be back.

Comment: I recommend to add a part for the clang plugin, clang is modulized designed, and write a plugin is easy

Comment: I advice against using `dynamic_cast` until normal virtual functions mechanism is thoroughly mastered. At any rate, plugins are written after the core program is frozen, so there's nothing to `dynamic_cast` to.

Answer (score 1):

Possible, well, this way you manually somewhat reimplement dynamic dispatch and make your class a kind of sealed.

```cpp
struct Base {
    Base(std::string type_id): type_id(std::move(type_id)) {}
    template<class F> auto visitThis(F &&f) const;
    template<class F> auto visitThis(F &&f);
private:
    std::string type_id;
};

struct Child1: Base { Child1(): Base("Child1") {}};
struct Child2: Base { Child2(): Base("Child2") {}};

template<class F> auto Base::visitThis(F &&f) const {
    if(type_id == "Child1") {
        return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f),
                           static_cast<Child1 const *>(this));
    }
    else if(type_id == "Child2") {
        return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f),
                           static_cast<Child2 const *>(this));
    }
    else throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported subclass");
}

template<class F> auto Base::visitThis(F &&f) {
    if(type_id == "Child1") {
        return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), static_cast<Child1 *>(this));
    }
    else if(type_id == "Child2") {
        return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), static_cast<Child2 *>(this));
    }
    else throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported subclass");
}

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Base> b1 = std::make_unique<Child1>();
    b1->visitThis([](Child1 const *ch) { std::cout << "Hi, Ch1!\n"; });
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not making myself clear. I will update my question. Actually, I need this trick in my plugin system. In another word, I don't even know there is a `SubClassA` or `SubClassB`, and maybe there is another `SubClassC`. What I know is only the class name in string variable, like here `type_id`. So how can I perform `static_cast` stuff?

Comment: Visitor is good for a closed system where all subclasses are known in advance, but not for an open system that allows plugins to be added at any time.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Not exactly true.

Comment: `visitThis` depends every one of the subclasses. If somebody wants to add a new subclass after you release the main program, you need to recall the program and redo `visitThis`to accommodate the new subclass. Thus you cannot add a subclass at any time, but only before you release the main program. Thus there cannot be a plugin developed independently from the main program. These are simple undeniable facts. If you want to demonstrate a system that doesn't possess this property, you are more than welcome.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. You might have noted "sealed" in the beginning of my post.

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not ship enough information in binaries to write new code.

Dynamically linked C++ code do not carry enough information for other dynamically linked code to build a copy of the class at link time.

So there is no way, short of shipping a C++ compiler, to do exactly what you are asking.  I have heard of some people who go that far, and embed C++ compilers into their hand-grown "dynamic linking" environment, but usually by that point you are better off with using a language where that is a built-in feature, or not using the raw C++ object model and using something reflection-enabled.

It is quite likely that the underlying problem you are trying to solve using this technique can be solved in C++, if one exists.